# How can I capture the result of AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX request:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'script.php?val1=' + value1 + '&val2=' + value2,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
         var newValue1 = data[0];
         var newValue2 = data[1];
     }
 });
```

If I try:

```
console.log(newValue1, newValue2);
```

They will appear as undefined. How can I capture them ?

Comment: What does the console print when you `console.log(data)`?

Comment: I believe you want `data.data` - usually that variable is called _response_ or `res` for short and you get `res.data`

Comment: It prints: "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is asynchronous. You must access those values in `success` callback.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'script.php?val1='+value1+'&val2='+value2,
      dataType: "json",             
      success: function(data){                             
           var newValue1 = data[0];
           var newValue2 = data[1]; 
           console.log(newValue1, newValue2); // correct
     }
   });

// incorrect
// console.log(newValue1, newValue2);
```

Comment: Yeah but I want to access them outside the success because I want to pass them in another function later. It seems that their lifetime ends inside the success

Comment: then inside the callback `success` do assign those values to another object that is defined in outer scope

Comment: I tried. If I assign them like global to zero for example and try to access them after the AJAX call they will have the value of zero again. It's like the AJAX call's value dies inside success

Comment: Is there any alternative? I mean, am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: There is no alternative that will solve your problem because you cannot know "when" those values are assigned. The whole thing about programming asynchronously is you must do your work within the callback because that is the only place where you can access the result of the operation. To illustrate, imagine you order a pizza and then you want to eat it before it's been delivered. It's the same issue with asynchronous functions, you have to wait for the pizza before you can eat it. ;)

Comment: @laika the only edit I would recommend for what should be the only accepted answer would be to change the word "should" in your second sentence to "must".

Answer (score 1):

The reason your variables "die" inside the `success` as you said in your comment, is because you are using the `var` keyword to declare them, which creates the variable in **that** scope (the `success` callback).

So, declare your variables with `var` outside of your ajax so the scope is **global** (global: assuming that code is at the very top scope -not inside a module or something), and use it like this:

```
var newValue1, newValue2; // sets the scope here

$.ajax({
     url: 'script.php?val1=' + value1 + '&val2=' + value2,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
         newValue1 = data[0]; // no var keyword
         newValue2 = data[1]; // their scope is already defined outside of ajax
     }
 });
```

newValue1 and newValue2 can be accessed from within the success callback and of course outside of it since their scope allows it:

```
console.log(newValue1, newValue2);
```

**Beware**: in your code if you are expecting to read these values **outside** of the success callback and you are **expecting values that has been set by the success callback**, you must make sure of course that **the success callback has completed**. There are many ways to do that but is beyond the scope (no pun intended!) of this answer.

see example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gr5qxk4c/

**Extra tip:** beware of variable shadowing!

```
var myvar = "myvar is global!";

function hideTheScope()
{
    var myvar = "nope, since we have the same name here it is a different scope";
    console.log(myvar);
}

console.log(myvar); // "myvar is global!"

hideTheScope(); // "nope, since we have the same name here it is a different scope";
```

Comment: Nope but thanks for playing. You can only access the result of an asynchronous operation within its callback. In your explanation, you say you can access the global value "later", but neglect to mention when that might be. Consider if the ajax call takes 100ms to return, or 1 second, or 10 seconds....you cannot know when "later" is. Since there is no way to know this outside of the callback, your answer is not correct which is why I have downvoted it.

Comment: @RobRaisch my answer is correct. You can access the variable anytime you want. That does not imply that a callback has completed; thats up to the programmer to make sure so. The problem here is the scope and thats what im demonstrating. These variables are no longer undefined as in OPs situation. Of course feel free to vote as you please

Comment: @RobRaisch you are also correct my wording may imply that! Hmm i cant edit my answer right now on mobile feel free to edit!

Comment: You wrote: "then **later** you can do: console.log(newValue1, newValue2);" When do you imagine "later" might be?

Comment: @RobRaisch yes that needs better wording plz edit answer im on mobile its anightmare to type

Comment: @RobRaisch updated the answer per our discussion, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @ Sharky - cool but your changes don't address the fundamental problem! Say I click your first button (which triggers an asynchronous ajax call and then immediately click the second button (which prints the values), but the ajax call takes longer to complete than the time it takes for me to click the button, i.e. the second click occurs whilst the ajax call is still "in flight". What would your values be? The real problem (as I describe below) is that you have no way of knowing when the ajax call completes, or *even if it completes at all!*

Comment: @RobRaisch 1/2 i knowwhat you are talkingabout,i am a professional. I agreewith what you said,but i **deliberately** have chosen to just answer thisquestion on **exactly** what was asked. If that guy wants to read the variables out of scope of the success callback,then **a)** its his problem **b)** he **may have his reasons** and he does not care if the call(s) succeded, failed,or stuck at loading. Fancy a global counter `var how_many_ajax_calls_have_succeeded;` where you justclick a button to show that (even if there are lots of calls currently on hold).So i just addressed the "scope" problem

Comment: 2/2 but **yes in most common scenarios**, if you want to get the value of an asynchronous call, you just have to wait in a "success" or "done" or "finally" or whatever of these kind of callbacks your framework/libraries provide you.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem the OP is facing is a misunderstanding of the concept of **asynchronous programming**.

Webster's defines asynchronous as '*not simultaneous or concurrent in time*' which in this case means: '*not occurring within a predictable period of time*'.

As I explained above, since you cannot know "when" your `ajax` call completes and makes its result available to you, even assigning the result to a global won't work as you expect. You can only operate on the returned value within the callback.

Consider how the time passes in your program:

- 00:000 make your call via ajax
- 00:006 attempt to access the result which **fails** *because there is no result yet*
- (...time passes...)
- 00:500 ajax call completes and triggers callback

This illustrates the **asynchronous** nature of programming in `Node`: things in your program occur at ***unpredictable*** times so you cannot assume the result of an operation will be available *outside of the context of the operation itself*.

To program effectively in `Node`, you have to think about your program flow in terms of multiple, *seemingly* concurrent operations that only produce results when they complete and pass them to the supplied callback.

Answer (score -1):

you should try this

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'script.php?val1=' + value1 + '&val2=' + value2,
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
     var newValue1 = data.d

 }
```

I dont know how you send the data back from the server side but if you are sending 1 var the .d will give it to you